# jQuery $.getJSON() not returning anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a script that i'm using to experiment a bit with jQuery since i just started learning.

the script is supposed to read  a .json file and display some data in a div.

```
function jQuerytest()
{
    $.getJSON( "books/testbook/pageIndex.json", function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            $("div").append("<p>" + field + "</p>");
        });
    });
}
```

here is the html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/book.js"></script>
<script>jQuerytest();</script>
</head>

<body>
<div></div>
  <figure id=fig><img onClick="jQuerytest()" src="figures/test620x620.png"/>
  </figure>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doens't display anything.

Comment: Open up your debug tools in browser of choice and look at the network traffic.  Ensure that the request `books/testbook/pageIndex.json` is returning with HTTP/200.

Comment: If you get 200 status code and a response, then just add `return false;` statement at the end of `jQuerytest()`

Comment: First of all, [**is you JSON file correct**](http://jsonlint.com)?

Comment: And check if your JSON is valid, with `.fail(function () { console.log(arguments); })`. You will get `parse error` if your json is incorrect.

Comment: ok, i tried the .fail() and .error() and it turned out that it did fail. so I looked at my json file and it looked alright to me i copied it into the JSON validator and it said it was fine. so i created a new json file from scratch and copied the json into it and tried using that file and now it's working for some reason..

Answer (score 8):

If your JSON File is valid (You can test here: http://jsonlint.com/)
Use the success and error callback to finally get information why it's not working.

```
function jQuerytest(){
    $
      .getJSON( "books/testbook/pageIndex.json")
      .success(function(result) {
          $.each(result, function(i, field) {
               $("div")
                .append("<p>" + field + "</p>");
          });
      })
      .error(function(error){
          console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, no?

Comment: @JTorres I don't think so. it teaches fishing. That's all we can suggest here, check the errors.

Comment: @undefined Yes... but it doesn't actually solve the problem (because we don't yet know what it is or) or teach future visitors about the solution to the currently unknown problem.

Comment: Now all the steps required to determine why it's not working are described in answear